# GCP VPN tunnel as default gateway for Internet connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am setting up Google Computing Engine virtual machine with site-to-site VPN to our office.
I want the virutal machine to send/receive all traffic via the VPN tunnel.
By default, it communicates with on-premise hosts via VPN tunnel but it communicates with Internet hosts directly (not via VPN tunnel).  I don't want such direct Internet communication.
How can I make the VPN tunnel as default gateway for the virtual machine?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Note that, initially, a [VPC network has a default route](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/routes#routingpacketsinternet); that is, a route with these characteristics: 
    destination: 0.0.0.0/0 
    next hop: default Internet gateway
2. You are able to delete the default route and replace it with a custom route to direct traffic, including “Internet” traffic, elsewhere. Specifically:

   - If using a VPN tunnel with static routing (route based VPN or policy based VPN), you'd simply create a new, custom static route with these characteristics:
      
     destination: 0.0.0.0/0 
     next hop: the desired VPN tunnel, by name

Just be sure that the remote traffic selector (as configured on the Google end) is 0.0.0.0/0. This must match the local traffic selector on the remote (peer network) end.

You can create routes manually when you create the VPN tunnels; see the gcloud version of these guides: [policy-based](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/creating-policy-based-vpns) and [route-based](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/creating-route-based-vpns).

For existing tunnels, you can always simply add a custom static route, please take a look at following docs which can help you:

[Static route parameters](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/routes#individualroutes)

[Adding a static route](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-routes#addingroute)

- If using a VPN tunnel with dynamic (BGP) routing, the traffic selectors are 0.0.0.0/0 by default, but you'd need to configure your peer network's router to advertise a route with the 0.0.0.0/0 destination to the Cloud Router associated with the VPN tunnel. Then the Cloud Router would automatically apply a custom dynamic route to the VPC network. For the custom dynamic route to apply to all VMs in all regions of the network, make sure the VPC network's dynamic routing mode is global dynamic routing.

Details about the dynamic routing mode and how it affects custom dynamic routes, review these links: ([routing_for_hybrid_networks](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#routing_for_hybrid_networks) and [switch-dynamic-routing](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc#switch-dynamic-routing)).

3. Once they have a custom route with destination 0.0.0.0/0 and appropriate next hop, they can delete the default route; that is, the one with these characteristics: 
   destination: 0.0.0.0/0 
   next hop: default Internet gateway

Note that route priorities for custom static routes can be configured in the VPC network, but that the priority of a custom dynamic route is based on the MED of the route from the peer router.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!  I followed your answer and I successfully created the default route to VPN tunnel. Now all the trafiic go through VPN tunnel as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make the VPN tunnel as default gateway for the virtual
>   machine?

Create a VPC route (0.0.0.0/0) to your network thru your VPN endpoint in the VPC. Give it a higher priority (lower number) than the default gateway. For next hop specify the IP address or instance ID (if you have your own software VPN) or the VPN tunnel (if a Google VPN gateway).

You can also use `Instance tags` to route traffic for only specific instances instead of the entire VPC network.

Comment: Thanks for your swift answer!  Removing default route to Internet seems better way for my case instead of giving higher priority to the custom default route.

Comment: @ikex98 - I don't recommend the other method, but it is technically valid. Tip: pay attention to bandwidth costs.